# LocalNotification not working [IOS] - PushNotificationIOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, push-notification, localnotification

I'm trying to implementing local notification in IOS using this [@react-native-community/push-notification-ios](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios#react-native-communitypush-notification-ios) package.

I followed all the documentation properly. Still, LocalNotification is not working.

This is my environment config:
- `react-native` : `0.61.4`
- `@react-native-community/push-notification-ios --save` : `1.0.5`

I did the following things,

1. `npm i @react-native-community/push-notification-ios --save`
2. `cd ios && pod install`
3. Updated `AppDelegate.m` as per described [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios#update-appdelegatem)
4. Made build : react-native run-ios --device "iPhone X"
5. Then calling function in my js like this,

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
.
.
.
componentDidMount(){
  PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('localNotification', this._onNotification);

  PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();
  PushNotificationIOS.presentLocalNotification({
    alertBody: 'Test Notification'
  });
}

_onNotification(notification) {
  console.log(notification._alert);
}
.
.
.
```

- By the way, It requests for permissions when the first-time app opens & also I'm getting `console.log` of notification but not getting any local notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when the app running in the foreground, you won't be able to see the notification. You can call the local schedule function and quick hide app to the background, then you will see the notification.

Source Code:-

```
PushNotificationIOS.localNotificationSchedule({
      message: "Local push notification",   //mandatory
      number: 1,
      date: new Date(Date.now() + (5 * 1000)) // Schedule in 5 secs
    });
```

Comment: Ohh so in IOS it is not possible to get a notification when an app is running. Then what is the meaning of providing `PushNotificationIOS.presentLocalNotification` this type of functions?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/ios-10-notifications-inshorts-all-in-one-ad727e03983a/

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this "Well, when the app running in the foreground, you won't be able to see the notification."